# What Are the Hardware Requirements of Kubernetes Master Node

Tags: docker, deployment, kubernetes

We are trying to setup one cluster with 25 worker nodes and 1 master node. Before doing that, we need to choose the hardware, especially for the master node.

How to estimate the hardware resources we need? Do hardware requirements of the master node relate to the size of the cluster? Is there something like an official hardware recommendation or resource rules we can follow?

Answer (score 4):

Well, your question is very general. All depends on many factors, resources you want to use, how nodes will be used, for what purposes, if there will be `HorizontalPodAutoscaler`/`ClusterAutoscale`r, what environment you want to use, quota settings, resource limits/requirements and many more.

However, if you would go to [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/) you will be able to check current Kubernetes version capabilities:

> At v1.19, Kubernetes supports clusters with up to 5000 nodes. More specifically, we support configurations that meet all of the following criteria:
>
> - No more than 5000 nodes
> - No more than 150000 total pods
> - No more than 300000 total containers
> - No more than 100 pods per node

If you would like to run Kubernetes on local environment, you would need to read a lot about [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) and [Highly Available clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/).

However, if you would decide to use cloud environment like `Google Kubernetes Engine`, `Amazon EKS`, `Azure Kubernetes Service`, `OpenShift`, etc; you will be able to find those requirements in specific cloud provider documentation.

In `Kubernetes documentation` you will be able to find some general information for [Size of master and master components](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/best-practices/cluster-large/#size-of-master-and-master-components) in [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) and [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/)

> On GCE/Google Kubernetes Engine, and AWS, kube-up automatically
> configures the proper VM size for your master depending on the number
> of nodes in your cluster. On other providers, you will need to
> configure it manually. For reference, the sizes we use on GCE are:
>
> - 1-5 nodes: n1-standard-1
> - 6-10 nodes: n1-standard-2
> - 11-100 nodes: n1-standard-4
> - 101-250 nodes: n1-standard-8
> - 251-500 nodes: n1-standard-16
> - more than 500 nodes: n1-standard-32
>
> And the sizes we use on AWS are
>
> - 1-5 nodes: m3.medium
> - 6-10 nodes: m3.large
> - 11-100 nodes: m3.xlarge
> - 101-250 nodes: m3.2xlarge
> - 251-500 nodes: c4.4xlarge
> - more than 500 nodes: c4.8xlarge

It's also worth to mention that some cloud environments (like GKE) master node are managed by `cloud provider`. Therefore you don't need to worry about master but you can focus on other aspects like [HPA](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/), [CA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) or `Network configuration`.

As last thing you can read [Kubernetes Capacity Planning](https://platform9.com/blog/kubernetes-capacity-planning/) article.

Comment: well, if we want to purchase one master node for provisioning cluster with 20-30 workers, each of these workers has 8 gpu cards. Then what is the hardware requirement for this master node,  how much memory and cpu do we need?

Comment: this is a on-premise cluster, not building by cloud platform